# Copy content from local folder to remote folder in python

Tags: python, file, copy, remote-server

I am trying to copy files from  a local folder to a remote windows share using python. So the main requirement is to move files from source folder (which keeps changing) to a Remote Share:

Not sure what I am doing wrong but below is what I have tried to so far:

```
# Move the archive file to DVD Burner Box
 destPath = '\\\\10.10.10.10\\DestFolder\\'
 destFolder = destPath + ('%s_%s\\') %(id1,id2)
 srcArchFolderPath = '.\\prepared\\%s_%s\\' %(id1,id2)
 srcArchFiles = os.listdir(srcArchFolderPath)

try:
    os.makedirs(destFolder)
except OSError:
    pass

shutil.copytree (srcArchFiles,destFolder,ignore=None)
```

The sourceFolderPath keeps changing on every run with different input.

Ex: it can be .\prepared\1_2 or .\prepared\2_3 which will keep changing on every script run.

If I print srcArchFiles it shows list of the folders which exists in  srcArchFolderPath succesfully. Also os.makedirs(destFolder) creates a folder succesfully on the remote share location. But the files copy is failing and not sure why it's failing, I belive I am not doing something right with shutil.

Following is the error I am seeing:
File "C:\Python26\lib\shutil.py", line 140, in copytree
names = os.listdir(src)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Any help in correcting this is much appreciated.

Comment: could you choose a protocol like scp to transfer and use a library like paramiko_scp?

Answer (score 0):

`srcArchFiles` is a list of folders. [`shutil.copytree`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) needs one folder as the first parameter.

You have to use a loop to copy each folder.

```
for foldername in srcArchFiles:
    shutil.copytree (foldername, destFolder, ignore=None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @Matthias. I tried making the change by appending the
    for foldername in srcArchFiles:
How, ever it ends up giving below error:
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: '\
\\\10.10.10.10\\DestFolder\\id1_id2\\'
I have also commented out the os.mkdirs part so that the folder doesn't get created.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I added 

     if os.path.exists(destFolder)
        shutil.rmtree(destFolder)

Thanks again for showing right direction. +1

Answer (score 0):

I've found a good solution here: [Execute remote commands on windows like psexec (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577945-execute-remote-commands-on-windows-like-psexec/)